# Facebook style Cover photo upload, reposition, crop and save using php and jquery in bootstrap3

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a newbie to web development and am trying to build my first website. I use PHP, Jquery and Bootstrap3 for my development. I want to add a Faceebook like cover photo upload and reposition feature on my site and it's been bit of a head ache. I have implemented all the features successfully by taking help from tutorials available [here](http://w3lessons.info/2014/08/31/facebook-style-cover-image-reposition-using-jquery-php/) and [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2015/02/facebook-style-background-image-upload.html), but both of them are not perfect.

In both the tutorials, everything works fine until the final stage where you save the new repositoned image.

1. In the first approach, upon save, the new position of the image, the height and width of the container div are taken as inputs and a new image is generated using imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);. The original image is saved separately and used if you want to reposition again.
2. In the second approach, simply the new position of the image is saved in the db and the same is set as "margin-top" for the (so called) repositioned image on page load.

**Problems**

1. The first approach is actually doing a good job by saving the images separately. However, the issue here is, the dimensions of the new image are set as per the dimensions of the container div. Since my container div is **responsive**, the height and width vary on screen size, and so does the actual size of the image. This is a disaster because if you crop the image on a mobile screen, the width is set to 200px and the same image is loaded on large screens, where the container width is close to 600px. It creates an empty whitespace.
2. The second approach is not doing anything but position the same image using css. The original image of big size is unnecessarily loaded every time.

I have implemented the first approach and made a lot of changes to fit my needs.
The problem is better illustrated in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5un3.jpg) .gif image on Imagur. Also please refer my other Stack Overflow question [Scale down images effectively without losing aspect ratio or quality in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205440/scale-down-images-effectively-without-losing-aspect-ratio-or-quality-in-php) for more detailed explanation.

I have been struggling for more than a month now to figure out how to effectively crop the new image and save it so that it is consistent on all screen sizes.

I hope some expert can give me a solution for this so that I can launch my dream website without further delay.

Thank you

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that your two containers do not have the same aspect ratio. You'll either need to make them have the same aspect ratio or do some sort of scaling-to-fill like Twitter does.

Comment: @Math Nerd Productions: You absolutely right David. First thing is I have no idea how to set the aspect ratio accurately. Second thing is, even if I set it, the new image that will be generated will have a consistent height to width ratio, but its dimensions will still be a problem. Say in large screens, if the dimensions are 600x300, in small screen it will be 300x150 (i.e. 2:1).....doesn't solve the problem. I gave to crop/generate the repositioned image in a date fferent way, which is where I am stuck.

Comment: I am bad at explaining things, if I've still not made my point clear please feel free to point out the things that are not clear

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to generate a new image if the size of the screen changes. You can simply use percentages to maintain the original aspect ratio of the image.

You simply need to set the container to whatever width you want, then don't set the height, and set a child img to fill the entire width of the container. The height of the image will automatically scale to maintain the original aspect ratio:

```
div.aspect
{
    width: 75%;
}

div.aspect img
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwws6e1f/)

Comment: Nice approach, but this solves only the "white-space" problem. How am I supposed to handle the Repositioning and saving the new repositioned image !! It'd be great if there was some tutorial which did this perfectly......

Comment: From your Gif, it looked like you already had the saving part down. You just do it the same way you have been doing; the only difference is that you make sure that your two containers have the same aspect ratio by using the same image between the two of them. Or are you not cropping the image on-save?

Comment: Nerd Production: No I'm not cropping, I am actually generating a new image of width = container width, height = container height and position from top is what i get from jquery when I drag it. So that means, if my div is 300px * 150px (small screen), the image is generated for this width, whereas if the div is 600px * 300px, he image is generated for this width.

Comment: Hey, do you know any other website which has successfully implemented it or where can learn this kind of stuff !!

Comment: I know that gravatar actually has an engine that allows you to request any size of an image just by entering it in the URL